# Given a function $f$, how to prove that $range(f)$ has at least one interior point?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, vector-analysis

let $A,\,B$ be matrices of order n such that $A$ is nonsingular. Define mapping $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $$f(x)=Ax+B(x\times x)$$ where $x\times x=(x_1^2,\,x_2^2,\,\cdots ,\,x_n^2)^T\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\Vert x\Vert=\sqrt{x^Tx}$.
Prove that range(f) has at least one interior point.

---

My attempt:

since $A$ is nonsigular, it will suffice to prove the range of $$f(x)=x+B(x\times x)$$ has at least one interior point. And $f\not=0$, then there exists $y\not=0\in range(f)$. I want to prove that there exist $\delta>0$ such that $U(y,\,\delta)\subset range(f)$.

Comment: Your function is differentiable and has invertible derivative at zero. Hence by inverse mapping theorem it is homeomorphism onto some open ball around at zero.

Comment: @Slup Thank you!!!

Comment: @Slup Why not an official answer?